# XPages Mobile destination view not found: null when trying to navigate

Tags: xpages

Tried to create a mobile navigation using dataview or outline and the view renders ok
but when I click on an entry I get a dialog saying.

dojox.mobile.view#preformTransition: destination view not found: null

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

I'm Using 8.5.3 UP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error when the view your trying to transition to doesn't exist. So you should have a singlePageApp control with one or more appPage controls, the destination should be the value of a "pageName" attribute of one of the appPages.

Can you check that the pageName of the appPage exists and there's no typo etc.

Comment: Didn't make sense when I looked at you answer then but now it did.
The dataview requires an mobile application page in the same XPage with the name that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error when using the extlib outline control. Trying to open another xsp mobile page.

Comment: take a look at my answer and see does it help